A x = B with sgesvx of LAPACK
I am trying to solve problems of the form Ax = b by using the function sgesvx. However, it is returning a wrong solution for one test case: - 0.33333 * x_1 - 0.06667 * x_2 = - 0.133333, which is returning:

x_1 = 0.01346; And
x_2 = 0.

That, when applied over the expression - 0.33333 * x_1 - 0.06667 * x_2 = - 0.133333, gives - 0.0044866218 = - 0.133333, which is invalid. Below we have the code.
program Main

    implicit none

    external :: sgesv, sgesvx

    ! SCALAR 
    integer, parameter :: n=2,m=1
    integer :: i,j

    ! ARRAY 
    real(kind=8)    :: A(m,n),b(m),x(n)
    character(len=15)          :: subname

    ! LAPACK 
    integer                    :: IPIV(n),IWORK(n),INFO 
    character                  :: EQUED='N'
    real(kind=8)               :: R(n),C(n),RCOND,FERR(1),BERR(1),WORK(4*n),AF(m,n)

    !
    x(1) = 0
    x(2) = 0
    A(1,1) = -0.33333
    A(1,2) = -0.06667
    b(1) = -0.133333

    !
    do i = 1,m
        print *,"Constraint ",i,": "
        do j = 1,n
            print "(f10.5)",A(i,j)
        end do
        print *," = ",b(i)
    end do

    !
    call sgesvx( &
        'E', &
        'N', &
        n, &
        1, &
        A, &
        n, &
        AF, &
        n, &
        IPIV, &
        EQUED, &
        R, &
        C, &
        b, &
        n, &
        x, &
        n, &
        RCOND, &
        FERR, &
        BERR, &
        WORK, &
        IWORK, &
        INFO &
        )   

    if (INFO .lt. 0) then
        print *,INFO,"-th argument of sgesv is invalid"
    else if (INFO .gt. 0) then
        print *,INFO
    end if

    do j = 1,n
        print "(f10.5)",x(j)
    end do

end program Main

For compiling, simply type gfortran -O3 linearsystem.f90 -o main -lblas -llapack.

You are using kind=8 (for whatever that number happens to mean in your compiler) but your numerical constants are default precision.

Without checking anything else you are probably using double precision, which if I am right will probably need dgesvx I say probably as kind=8 is most likely double precision, but you can't be sure, and whatever it is just plain bad practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

It is good to provide an interface block for the LAPACK subroutines to have some type error checking.

Also I would get the much simpler dgesv driver going first before you try to use the expert driver.

Reading carefully, neither dgesv and dgesvx would work, since the matrix A must be squared: "where A is an N-by-N matrix" https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html-3.6.1/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html#ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.

sgesv[x] is also for a square A.

@francescalus but the question doesn't have a square matrix, or at least doesn't set one; what lapack is working on is a different question. In fact rereading the question in detail I'm not sure I understand what is trying to be achieved.

@IanBush, the question doesn't have a square matrix (except a 1x1 embedded in a 1x2, of course) but my comment was more to question rejecting dgesv for requiring a square A when sgesv also requires exactly the same square A.

Matheus, both sgesv[x] and dgesv[x] have exactly the same requirements on the matrices. The s... and d... variants just differ in whether they are to be used with single precision or double precision for the real variables in Fortran. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with the 2x1 matrix mathematically, but it certainly cannot be used with any of the mentioned subroutines.

@francescalus That's not how i read Matheus' comment. I think he's simply saying dgesv[x] is for square matrix, and by implication so are all the rest of that family of routines. I don't think he is saying that the prefix or suffix alters that.  Anyway, it's not that important.

Your use of "constraint", non-square A and [tag:linear-programming] suggests you have an under-specified linear system. If so, the LAPACK family is entirely the wrong tool: if you clarify we can move beyond the confusion we commenters have expressed.

Thank you so much. Perhaps, the function sgelqs https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/dd9/sgelqs_8f_ab64bdfe0ca8424c733df7489f66ddcc8.html#ab64bdfe0ca8424c733df7489f66ddcc8 would work. That is, solving the problem min || A*x - b ||.

It might but don't forget you need dgelqs for double precision.
